# Check if string is included in ReadonlyArray in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typeorm

The background is, I am trying to read from `.env` for the `DatabaseType` to construct a TypeORM connection, like so:

```js
const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: process.env.DB_CONNECTION, // A type of DatabaseType = 'mysql'|'postgres'|'sqlite'|...
  //...
}
```

Then above I have the list of supported `DatabaseType`s:

```js
const SUPPORTED_DB_TYPES = ['mysql', 'mariadb', 'postgres'] as const; // This array contains selected DatabaseType
```

The problem arises when I want to narrow down the type. This function currently works, but there is casting involved:

```js
const isSupportedDBType = (dbConnection: string|undefined): dbConnection is typeof SUPPORTED_DB_TYPES[number] =>
  dbConnection !== undefined &&
  ((SUPPORTED_DB_TYPES as readonly string[]).indexOf(dbConnection) > -1);

if(!isSupported(process.env.DB_CONNECTION)) {/*...*/}
```

I had to cast because of the following error if I removed `as readonly string[]`:

> Argument type of 'string' is not assignable to argument type of 'mysql'|'mariadb'|'postgres'

Is there a way to do it with the use of `as readonly string[]`?

Answer (score 2):

Note the type of `process.env`:

```js
export interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined
}
```

Your issue is caused by `process.env.DB_CONNECTION` which is `string | undefined`.

So when you're doing this:

```js
SUPPORTED_DB_TYPES.indexOf(process.env.DB_CONNECTION)
```

You're searching a `string` in an array of `'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres'`.

A solution would be to type `DB_CONNECTION` as `SUPPORTED_DB_TYPES[number]`, which would be bad because `DB_CONNECTION` can be something else. Else you can cast it as `any` which is not a bad idea.

Your solution, the use of `as readonly string[]`, is not a bad idea neither in my sense. Because this cast is scoped, and used because of the `indexOf` function which is too strict for your use.

Comment: Yes, I know, so I'm looking for a way around casting, because casting isn't exactly good.